# Как перенести информацию из локальной базы данных с одного компьютера на другой?

Tags: mysql, веб-программирование, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

После покупки нового компьютера (доступ к старому есть ещё есть), нужно перенести на него информацию из базы данных которая у меня там была (phpmyadmin). Подскажите пожалуйста как это делается, чтоб можно было уже каждый раз заходить через localhost, а не включать сервер на старом компьютере и на новом вводить ip адрес?

Comment: Гуглите mysqldump

Comment: Сделать `backup` базы на старом компе и восстановить его на новом. <br>
Вот [инструкция](https://support.managed.com/kb/a2034/how-to-backup-and-or-restore-your-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

1. Если выполнять дамп через консоль:

Делаем дамп базы на старом компьютере

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE > dump.sql
```

Переносим любым удобным способом дамп на новый компьютер.

Заливаем дамп в базу на новом компьютере

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE < dump.sql
```

2. Если через phpmyadmin:
   [Дамп через phpmyadmin](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214395738-phpMyAdmin-How-to-backup-or-export-a-database-or-table)

Answer (score 2):

Заходишь в phpMyAdmin выбираешь бузу. в верхней панеле Export или на русском Экспорт. Нажимаешь next(Вперёд), Качается файл. Этот файл на флешку и на другой комп. На другом комппе в phpMyAdmin import(Импортировать)->Выбрать файл->Вперёд. Всё готово.